# how to correctly read txt with backslash

Tags: python, string, backslash

i have this string in a txt file : `"\x16\x07\x11\x10\x1c\x13\x0e\x07\x004"`

i try to read it in python and split it.
instead of getting  this result :

```
['\x16', '\x07', '\x11', '\x10', '\x1c', '\x13', '\x0e', '\x07', '\x00', '4']
```

i get this :

```
['\\', 'x', '1', '6', '\\', 'x', '0', '7', '\\', 'x', '1', '1', '\\', 'x', '1', '0', '\\', 'x', '1', 'c', '\\', 'x', '1', '3', '\\', 'x', '0', 'e', '\\', 'x', '0', '7', '\\', 'x', '0', '0', '4']
```

how can i read this file correctly
code:

```
TextFile = open(FileName,"r")
ReadFile=TextFile.read()
print(list(ReadFile))
```

Comment: Short answer: Decode it with the `unicode-escape` codec. [This question is close to what you want, though it's a somewhat more complex case.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39283689/364696)

Answer (score -2):

You can do this:

```
TextFile = open(FileName,"r")
ReadFile = TextFile.read()
s = ReadFile.split('\\x')
del s[0]
for i in range(len(s)):
    s[i] = '\\x' + s[i]
print(s)
```

Comment: I somehow doubt they want the final entry in the list to be `\\x004`. This is why the `unicode-escape` codec exists; use it.

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this, (skipping the file stuff):

```
a = "\x16\x07\x11\x10\x1c\x13\x0e\x07\x004"
b = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    b.append(a[i])
```